# Реализовать метод hashCode в классе

Tags: java, hashcode

Привет. Нужно реализовать метод `hashCode` в классе. И у меня вопрос: Существуют какие-то встроенные функции, которые создают `hash` для каждого типа данных, или нужно  придумать формулу генерации самому?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как правильно писать метод hashCode хорошо описано в книге Дж. Блоха "Java. Эффективное программирование".

Существуют реализации библиотек, упрощающих жизнь. Например [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) имеет класс [HashCodeBuilder](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) позволяющий расчитывать hashCode по заданным полям.

Answer (score 2):

если вы работаете в INTELLIJ IDEA, то нажать alt+insert и выбрать hashcode and equals, в мастере выбрать поля которые будут участвовать в алгоритме

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с Java-7 создать метод `hashCode` весьма просто: воспользуйтесь [`Objects.hash`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#hash%28java.lang.Object...%29).

```
public class MyClass {
    boolean b;
    int i;
    double d;
    float f;
    String s;
    List<String> list;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(b, i, d, f, s, list);
    }
}
```

Не сработает, только если у вас есть поле-массив, его придётся специально обработать. Ну и есть некоторые накладные расходы, но обычно они незначительные.